# Does console.debug() affect react native performance in release mode

Tags: reactjs, react-native, console.log

I know that console.log() will affect react native's pref under release mode, this is stated very clear in the docs, but what about console.debug() and console.warn()?

Otherwise what's the best way to print debug message and not having to take all of them out every time we go into release? Since we will need these message in dev mode again.

Comment: The best way in my opinion is to write a wrapper for EVERY logging output. This can then be used to switch output streams in production with e.g. a telnet/ssh command on a listening debug port. This allows you to dynamically activate/deactive debug ouput on a running system and also allow for remote logging and many more features.

Answer (score 4):

If you check the documentation, there are some instructions on how to use the babel plugin to automatically remove all the console.* calls in the release builds.

According to it [1], you just need to install the plugin:
1)

```
npm i babel-plugin-transform-remove-console --save
```

2) Add this in your .babelrc file:

```
{
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
    }
  }
}
```

1 - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#using-console-log-statements

Answer (score 0):

There are webpack plugins that are designed to remove specific types of console statements, depending on how you configure them, so that you can, for example, remove only `console.debug` statements but the last time I tried, I didn't have much luck.

If you are building a React JS app with a recent version of React, for example 15.x, that was created with `create-react-app` and you eject it with `npm run eject`, you'll have two separate webpack configurations. You can modify the production configuration (`/config/webpack.config.prod.js`) and remove *all* console statement from your production build by modifying the existing `UglifyJsPlugin` configuration in the `plugins` section so that it looks something like this:

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  compress: {
    warnings: false,
    // Disabled because of an issue with Uglify breaking seemingly valid code:
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2376
    // Pending further investigation:
    // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/2011
    comparisons: false,

    // Drop console statements
    drop_console: true,          // <--- ADD THIS
  },
  output: {
    comments: false,
  },
  sourceMap: true,
}),
```

That's all you should need to do... but again, this will remove *all* console statements, not just `console.debug`